# Disable a gesture from firing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, gesture

I have a tap gesture on my view that I only want to be able to fire after a certain point and after a different function has run. My solution was to create a outlet for the tap gesture and then call the `Enabled` function setting to `TRUE` or `FALSE` as needed. The code looks like this, with the second function being the tap gestures

```
- (IBAction)butt:(id)sender
{
    if(game == FALSE)
    {
        tapges.enabled = FALSE;
        int sec;
        sec = arc4random() % 5;
        if(sec == 0){sec++;}
        sleep(sec);
        tapges.enabled = TRUE;
        game = TRUE;
        gun.hidden = FALSE;
        start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    }



}


- (IBAction)tap:(id)sender
{
    if(game == TRUE)
    {
        end = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        double total = end - start;
        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", total];
        ss.text = myString;
        game = FALSE;
        gun.hidden = TRUE;
        tapges.enabled = FALSE;
    }
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Even after the first function has set `tapges.enabled = FALSE` if you tap before it reaches `tapges.enabled = TRUE` it still just queues the tap function for running after the butt function runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to prevent a UIGestureRecognizer from firing (or to call another function before it fires) through using [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate) method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` but I think the issue is more a question of logic.

Not sure I entirely understand your task but wouldn't something more simple like:

```
- (IBAction)butt:(id)sender
{
    if(game == FALSE)
    {
     [self callOtherMethod];
    }
}
```

Or

```
- (IBAction)butt:(id)sender
{
    if(game == FALSE)
    {
     //do set up
    } else {
     // do other setup
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is measure the time between the event `start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];` at the end of function after the button has been pressed and the user tapping the screen. But I don't want it to respond to a tap or run/queue the tap function until the button function has been run and game is set to TRUE.

Comment: Then it seems like checking the var `game` state (as you are doing) should work

Comment: Yeah just realised but it give slightly inaccurate reading as it will let you tap the screen and just queue the screen function soon as `game = true`